# How add header information in the `$.getJSON` use ajax?

Tags: ajax

How add header information in the `$.getJSON` ajax ?

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data){
   for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
      $('#test').append('<p>' + data.rows[i].realName + '</p>');
   }
});
```

I want add `"PUBLICKKEY":"XXXX"` to the requst header, how to add in the `$.getJSON`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, since the shorthand function getJSON doesn't have all the options you would need. Switching tot the $.ajax function you can do the following

```
$.ajax({
   url:'test.json', 
   method: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function(xhr){
       xhr.setRequestHeader("PUBLICKKEY", "XXXX");
   }
   success: function(data){
      for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
          $('#test').append('<p>' + data.rows[i].realName + '</p>');
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: What mean of the `xhr` ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR - xhr is the wrapper around the XMLHTTPRequest object, which means you are adding a request header directly.